# Coin-flipping game, how can I justify a simplifying assumption?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

> Caitlin and Olivia are playing a game. Caitlin starts with a pile of $1000$ pennies and Olivia starts with a pile of $500$ pennies. On each turn, one of them flips a quarter. If the quarter comes up heads, Caitlin gives Olivia a penny. If the quarter comes up tails, Olivia gives Caitlin a penny. The game ends when one of them runs out of pennies. (It will probably take a while.) What is the probability that Caitlin wins?

I ended up getting ${2\over3}$. Here's how I did it. Without loss of generality, let's say Caitlin has $2$ pennies and Olivia has $1$ penny. Then Caitlin has a ${1\over2}$ chance of winning on the first turn. With the ${1\over2}$ chance that Olivia wins on the first turn, then there's a ${1\over2}$ chance that Caitlin wins back her penny, and then a ${1\over2}$ chance that Caitlin wins Olivia's only penny on the following turn. Continuing in this fashion, the probability that Caitlin wins is:$${1\over2} + {1\over2}\left({1\over2}\right)^2 + {1\over2}\left({1\over2}\right)^4 + \ldots = {{1\over2}\over{1 - {1\over4}}} = {2\over3}$$

I'm pretty confident this is correct. However, I'm not sure how I can justify my simplifying assumption that Caitlin has only $2$ pennies and Olivia only $1$. How do I justify that and make my approach rigorous?

Comment: Have you, say, tried the case of $4$ coins vs $2$ to see if you get the same result?

Comment: More broadly, this is an instance of the classical [Gambler's Ruin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin) problem, and the standard techniques and formulas can be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $p_n$ the probability of Caitlin winning if she begins with $n$ pennies. Since her pennies decrease or increase by 1 with probability 1/2, we may write the following condition
$$p_n = \frac 12 p_{n-1} + \frac 12 p_{n+1}.$$
From this, we may write the following [linear difference equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation)
$$p_{n+1} = 2p_n - p_{n-1},\quad p_0 = 0,\quad p_{1500} = 1.$$
The solution of such (since it has duplicate characteristic roots) is given by
$$p_n = a_1 + a_2n.$$
Imposing the boundary conditions, we obtain $a_1 =0$ and $a_2=1/1500$. In other words,
$$p_n=\frac 1{1500}n$$
and the desired probability is $p_{1000} = 2/3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let Caitlin's wealth on round $n$ be $W_n$, with $W_0 = 1000$. Then the sequence of random variables $\{ W_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ is a [martingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)): since the coin is fair, $\Bbb{E}[W_{n+1}|W_n] = W_n$.

Define the [stopping time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time) $T$, for a specific instance of this game, to be the minimum $n$ for which $W_n = 1500$ (i.e. Caitlin wins) or $W_n = 0$ (i.e. Caitlin loses). Since $|W_{\min \{T, n\}}| \leq 1500$ for all $n \geq 1$ by definition of $T$, the [optional stopping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem) applies and we have $$\Bbb{E}[W_T] = \Bbb{E}[W_0] = 1000.$$ But again by definition of $T$, $$\Bbb{E}[W_T] = 1500p + 0(1-p) = 1500,$$ where $p$ is the probability that Caitlin wins. So $1500p = 1000$, which means $p = 2/3$.

More generally, if Caitlin starts with wealth $W$ and Olivia starts with wealth $Y$ and the coins are fair, the same approach will always work to get the [classical result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin#Fair_coin_flipping) $$p = \frac{W}{W+Y},$$ where $p$ represents Caitlin's win probability.